# mysql_query into array/string and using Str_split?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to take serial numbers stored inside my SQL database, separate them using a comma as the delimiter "," (because it's already there to seperate them) then update my database using the serial number that remains for each row.

The problem is that some rows will contain more than one serial number. here is an example of what it looks like:

[image: ->As you can see here some rows have multiple serial numbers stored in them.]

Therefore, I need to break these into single serial numbers so that I have something I can work with.

I have attempted a few things with little success.

UPDATE:
This code:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

while ($serialsplit = mysql_fetch_array($serialcheck)) {

$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":"),$serialsplit['meta_value']);
echo $exploded[0];

}
```

Gives me THIS result:

```
101869999910621973310025107021067210330108321067010428100731087510040103311067910278109421087010960107981081410576101751027410963879310871946894461095410697107841078510817961796451046110995108979980967799081082610231100751006910074108231029710685107931076010820108198554108221307588249646107751088110165107911000710732106739393103041065710945854010328991810441854710996109971099810999110001100110442106351059496431080394431037488211067510655110057761943385351053910284843810856993110437104211078998188789990710882104438792853610693760310425109321008510883100941087810799103011086010720987710586109031087710893110141064310971103291070110894966910863105981030085381042710896109411105111026108881098611089110681094410647107789888785410982108747602107089930946593899098103571096595831021210689110531018910279101391078210438998210383103961101597309729107067733110699863103601071810885111261091410977840197431004210689b1082810989101461103410895110561105911058111208572111161108510163109391092495739876110521108310879826610666110251072699321093611119102251100210802964299931044510522108891102710436988710552101491045811080111221020187591097511028110701009341341231076059137111271072110177473109691107111057109011079010959759910310108351090610651781737833039839937337246655154254354154454655054546446346246511084108691069952047999661098531546730831830735235435835639739636337037936832836410207435899910953110161112311121106181103210909109084465001076795724471104010667469417422111005844785219246107039127107495275397810110061038793789377106136236278724872511129967458266266365799337765106585806326425295649884999443610827109055115171069187383154761030710743566714731573736737565843279265577870373811139619667666825615618579656916379468511035839877786886094955579588108241082168996497157971-110656708108998538981000388687283388458383488288151576047600827146858150110004460974010308716105321070874063199228968399870690866105776951008471257694364510372101387697286397389495210354735461536909972756310141087273473369477589972105401009964494196587607742693777938494684248430774996896793333494810838111361018654105411080186510291106510516686879101881098102463088011037111211139601108112269811171121113195950795087897511571236103211771108210341126113011194759427117011012107071377408915864114111351097109577599177721102010361273637129977607747709106209741323133910921224128112929361068116410928868136413341327108049385772013711374860114377307794137795413677221210132613659581338116014431332133013241176141111296431001212021372940341610988110388901203310a1112496011112511381113010261096959695951440897105857267288281102950872472510596103013941209137210211082109371269103898684102871133113212161306133797799581393127512549801264104193512537041422108913591166130412081112813161317144414511453145414528611027
```

Ideally, I want them to be split so I can call each one and update a line in my database according to its serial number.

EDIT 2: Query for $serialcheck

```
$queryserial = "SELECT * FROM order_item_meta WHERE meta_key='Serial Number'"; 
$serialcheck = mysql_query($queryserial);
```

Comment: Please **do not use** deprecated `mysql_*` functions! They will be removed in the future. *It's already removed actually* Please use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead.

Comment: @Jer Note: They *have been* removed already.

Comment: are you using old version of PHP? Update it to latest

Comment: What exactly isn't working? From your example data, explode(',',data) should work to split the column's data (even the ones without commas) into an array.

Comment: Ah sorry guys, I've actually got a code shiv running so I can still use older PHP 5 functions. (it is PHP 7 though) I'm just not up to par as I should be with 7 and obviously lacking the experience and knowledge to progress further.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the structure of the `$string` given to the `multiexplode()` function?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Updated my original question with what I am stuck on (code and output)

Comment: @Jer It's dead. Deleted. Gone forever. Not even pining for the fjords.

Comment: @GreeKatrina I'm passing it the array pulled from my query. I'll update the question now.

Comment: This schema violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should express this as a proper one-to-many relationship with a secondary table for storing serial numbers.

Comment: @tadman I have no idea what that means. - Correction, I read your links. I didn't create this schema I am merely using it for my business to track serial numbers on orders.

Comment: From the output shown, I think that may be a browser display - it would eliminate line feeds and they would appear to be one string. Use view source to confirm, or add a <br /> tag in your echo statement. Also, you don't need the multiexplode function since you are only exploding on the "," character. Lastly, use the print_r function to echo the result since it will be an array.

Comment: Also, you still haven't shown the result you expect, so your question isn't apparent.

Comment: @jay What I'm saying is this schema won't scale properly, it's going to be trouble to work with in the future, and if you don't know how to define a one-to-many relationship then that's something you'll need to address. There's a lot of books and guides on how to create a good schema, so find something you like and use it to understand how to do this properly. You won't regret doing it the right way because it'll make any queries you write in the future significantly easier.